# How to put the admin user always at the top of the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, arraylist

I made a table using `.map()` returning users from an array that has only one admin user.

I know the user is admin because it renders **name (ADM)** as follows:
I'm fetching the `user.email` from the users array and comparing it with the `user.email` from the context (it takes the data that is coming from auth0). If this email has the admin permission `(manage:accounts)`, then its name will be followed by **(ADM)**. I think this code can help to make the .sort(), but I couldn't do it

Here is the array : **The email michelle@gmail.com is the one with admin permission on auth0**

```js
const userList = [
  {
    name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@gmail.com', birth_date: '13/03/1954'
  },
  {
    name: 'Susy', email: 'suzy@gmail.com', birth_date: '23/03/1987'
  },
  {
    name: 'Michelle', email: 'michelle@gmail.com', birth_date: '31/10/1992'
  }
];
```

Here is the code I just described:

```js
{user.name} {user.email === context.user.email && context.user.permissions.includes('manage:accounts') && ('(ADM)')}
```

Here is the table I did:

```html
<TableContainer component={Paper} elevation={0}>
  <S.TableContent>
  {userList?.length && userList.map((user, index) => (
    <TableRow key={index}>
      <S.TableCellIcon>
        <S.UserIcon src={'/icon_profile.svg'} alt='Ícone do perfil' />
      </S.TableCellIcon>
      <S.TableCellUser>
        <span>{user.name} {user.email === context.user.email && context.user.permissions.includes('manage:accounts') && ('(ADM)')}</span>
        <p>{user.email}</p>
      </S.TableCellUser>
      <S.TableCellLastAcess>
        Último acesso: <b>{user.birth_date}</b>
      </S.TableCellLastAcess>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
  </S.TableContent>
</TableContainer>
```

Thank you for your help <3

Comment: If you're not concerned about how the rest of the array is sorted, I think I would just find the admin in the array ahead of time, `splice()` it out, and `unshift()` it to add it the beginning of the array.

Comment: but I don't want to change my array, I want the table to keep showing all users. That's why I think .sort() is the best option

Comment: Calling `sort()` on your array will also change it. The difference is sorting everything vs. moving one item.